# how to add phone field to interface create new lead marketo

Tags: marketo

it's possibe to add a field for example "phone field" in the interface for create a new Leads of marketo ?

[image]

Comment: Please add code to show what you've already tried

Comment: Please explain more.

Comment: i think marketo don't have a place to add a code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to customize this Lead Creation widget.

What I'd suggest is to create a Marketo form and embed it on some internal page you have.

In this form you can include all the fields you want the marketers to fill out when they manually creating new leads - phone number for example.

TIP: Make sure you have some javascript installed on this page which removes the mkto cookie from the marketer's browser - otherwise, all his/her web activity will be associated with the newly created lead.